# Merge two, unequal, two-dimensional arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$addresses = array(array('address' => 'Address1', 'housenumber' => 22, 'zipcode' => '1234 AB', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'country' => 'Netherlands'),
                   array('address' => 'Address2', 'housenumber' => 62, 'zipcode' => '1234 AC', 'city' => 'Rotterdam', 'country' => 'Netherlands'),
                   array('address' => 'Address3', 'housenumber' => 63, 'zipcode' => '1234 AD', 'city' => 'Eindhoven', 'country' => 'Netherlands'));

$tasks = array(array('task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note 1'),
               array('task_action' => 'deliver', 'note' => 'Some note 2'),
               array('task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note 3'));
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
$NewArray = array(array('address' => 'Address 1', 'housenumber' => 22, 'zipcode' => '1234 AB', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'country' => 'Nederland', 'task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note'),
                  array('address' => 'Address 2', 'housenumber' => 62, 'zipcode' => '1234 AC', 'city' => 'Rotterdam', 'country' => 'Nederland', 'task_action' => 'deliver', 'note' => 'Some note 2'),
                  array('address' => 'Address 3', 'housenumber' => 63, 'zipcode' => '1234 AD', 'city' => 'Eindhoven', 'country' => 'Nederland', 'task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note 3'));
```

I tried things like:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($addresses); $x++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($tasks); $x++) {
        $addresses[$x][] = $tasks[$x];
    }
}
```

Can someone provide me a little help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at this as a multi-dimensional array, but really it's a list of entries.

You have a list of addresses and a list of tasks, and you want to combine them:

```
foreach ($addresses as $index => $_) {
    $addresses[$index] = array_merge($addresses[$index], $tasks[$index]);
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! But can you explain the `$_` to me?

Comment: It has to do with the foreach syntax. You can change it for a `for` loop if you want. We don't need the second parameter but you need to include it to get the `$index`. You can change `$_` for `$address` and `$addresses[$index]` for `$address`. I thought this was clearer.

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
$address = array(array('address' => 'Address1', 'housenumber' => 22, 'zipcode' => '1234 AB', 'city' => 'Amsterdam', 'country' => 'Netherlands'),
                 array('address' => 'Address2', 'housenumber' => 62, 'zipcode' => '1234 AC', 'city' => 'Rotterdam', 'country' => 'Netherlands'),
                 array('address' => 'Address3', 'housenumber' => 63, 'zipcode' => '1234 AD', 'city' => 'Eindhoven', 'country' => 'Netherlands'));

$tasks = array(array('task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note 1'),
               array('task_action' => 'deliver', 'note' => 'Some note 2'),
               array('task_action' => 'pick up', 'note' => 'Some note 3'));

$i = 0;
foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
    $NewArray[] = $value + $tasks[$i];
    $i++;
}

var_dump($NewArray);
```